# SQL Custom filter in Metabase not show custom field with use [[ ]] to

Tags: metabase

I'm trying build a custom filter based on a string field. In my case I try map a field "nome_setor" in other table. If I try use variable with a text field works fine:

[image]

If I change this for a custom field using another table not works. In this case not show the filter:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use custom fields when you compare it values with some other column.

For you case to work, remove the table alias from the custom field you gonna use, and define your conditional snippet like so:

```
[[AND {{hithere}}]]
```

Now when you select the custom field, it should work. But you `LIKE` won't.

Hope it helps